# It matrices are similar, then they have the same Jordan canonical form (up to permuting the Jordan blocks)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

**Problem:** If two matrices are similar, then they have the same Jordan canonical form (up to the ordering of the Jordan blocks).

**Proof sketch I'm trying to follow:** If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then they have the same minimal polynomial $p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$. Treating $B$ as a linear operator on $V$, then $B$ has a primary decomposition
$$V=V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n$$

where $V_i = ker(p_i(B)^{e_i})$.

If $A = PBP^{-1}$, then $P\left(V_1\right) \oplus \ldots \oplus P\left(V_n\right)$ is the primary decomposition for $A$. If $V_i$ corresponds to the prime polynomial $\left(x-\lambda_i\right)$ and $V_i=W_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus W_k$ is a decomposition into cyclic invariant subspaces for $B-\lambda_i I$, then $P\left(V_i\right)=P\left(W_1\right) \oplus \ldots \oplus P\left(W_k\right)$ is a decomposition of $P\left(V_i\right)$ into cyclic invariant subspaces for $A-\lambda_i I$. Then $A$ and $B$ have the same Jordan canonical form.

**Question:** How do I go from $A = PBP^{-1}$ to $P\left(V_1\right) \oplus \ldots \oplus P\left(V_n\right)$ being the primary decomposition for $A$?

Comment: $P(V_i )= ker(p_i^{e_i}(A)).$

Comment: $(PBP^{-1})(Pv)=P(Bv)$. Conjugation is used as "transport of structure."

Comment: @AnneBauval How so?  I don't quite see it.

Comment: @runway44 How does this help?  So if $v_i$ belongs to $V_i$, then $P(Bv_i) = 0$?